# How to identify used variables in a statistical model in R

Tags: r, model, random-forest, r-caret, predict

I'm predicting data by a model generated with random forest. How can I identify the predictor variables used in the model?
I cant get rid of the error: "Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'ENERGY' not found".

ENERGY column is the column I'm trying to predict and not used as a variable in model generation.
And this column does not exist in varImp(DATA)$importance.

```r
predict(model_RF2, newdata = predData)
```

Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'ENERGY' not found

```r
varImp(DATA)$importance
```

As the reply of this code, names of 60 columns listed; and ENERGY is not in this vector.

Is there any other method to identify the columns used in model ?

Answer (score 0):

The important part of the prediction is to verify that new data frame (predData in your case) has the same column names as the original data.
So if your original data had ENERGY column, you have to be sure that your predData has it as well.

See documentation here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rpart/versions/4.1-13/topics/predict.rpart

Quote: "**newdata** data frame containing the values at which predictions are required. The predictors referred to in the right side of formula(object) must be present by name in newdata."

Comment: But it's not a predictor, it's the column I'm predicting.

Comment: 1. I've generated a linear model, and added it's prediction to data (column name: LM)
2. I've generated an RF model (also used the new column "LM"), and added it's prediction to data (column name: RF1)
3. I've generated a new column from the column I tried to predict. dataNUM$ener=dataNUM$ENERGY/dataNUM$col2*8000/log(dataNUM$col5+5) 
4. Generated a new model predicts ener and found ENERGY by reversing above formula. (RF1 and LM columns not used in this model)

In predData, I could predict ENERGY by the linear model and 1st random forest,  but cant predict with 2nd random forest model.

Answer (score 0):

RF algorithm shows the importances that are used to predict a certain variable. However, it doesn't show the importance of the variable that is going to be predicted. Since you are predicting 'ENERGY' variable, it is normal that you don't see it's name on the list. Also;

```
importance(model_RF2)
```

and

```
varImpPlot(model_RF2)
```

can show you the columns (variables) that are used in the model. varImpPlot also pictures a nice graph.

Comment: Since I used caret package of rf, both functions turn up error.  The code chunk I used to generate model is: ´´´r 
 train(ener~. -ENERGY -LM -RF1 -LAPS , data=dataNUM, method="rf", metric=metric, ntree=10, tuneGrid=tunegrid, trControl=control,importance=T)
´´´
errors: 
> importance(model_RF2)  
Error in UseMethod("importance") : 
  no applicable method for 'importance' applied to an object of class "c('train', 'train.formula')"    

> varImpPlot(model_RF2)  
Error in varImpPlot(model_RF2) : 
  This function only works for objects of class `randomForest'

Comment: If you can write the whole code block, I can help better. I cannot say which is the models name, which one is the prediction function from your comment above. If you use four spaces before the code block, it will look better and neat.